# Замена переносов

Tags: jquery, javascript

Мне нужна функция, которая заменяет несколько переносов на один, пробелы и переносы с конца и начала строки убирает (как `trim` на `php`), заменяет перенос на какую-то определенную строку. И все это мне нужно реализовать на языке `javascript` (еще можно jQuery и возможно другие js библиотеки).

Буду очень благодарен вам, если поможете. Пожалуйста

Comment: Можно тремя разными функциями. Просто подкиньте идею

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в `jQuery` есть расширение `$.trim`. я думаю легко догадаться, что именно оно делает. ну а в остальном может помочь вот [эта статья](http://javascript.ru/String/replace)

с переносом, надеюсь, поможет вот [эта статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: А перенос, это что за символ?

Comment: В нормальных браузерах - "\n", в старых IE - "\r\n"

Answer (score 2):

Какое расширение jquery? **Зачем???**

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/, "$1");
};
```

И кстати - в современных браузерах есть нативная поддержка этого метода, поэтому лучше написать так:

```
 if (!String.prototype.trim) {
    String.prototype.trim = function () {
        return this.replace(/^\s*(\S*(?:\s+\S+)*)\s*$/, "$1");
    };
 }
```

---

```
   var str = "    HELLO     ";
   console.log(str.trim()); // "HELLO";
```

Comment: Ну раз я подключил jQuery, то зачем мне лишнюю память тратить?

Comment: Лишнюю память? xD ок кэп...